# How to do an if this is not found then... Selenium node.js

Tags: node.js, selenium, webdriver

This might be a dumb question but how can i do an if this is not found then... in my case ? I know that i have to use !== but i don't know how to handle it in my case... Here is the code :

```
 if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@name, 'Discord')]"))) {
    fs.writeFile("NOTTHIS.txt", '${String(await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@name, 'Discord')]")))}', err => {
      if (err) throw err;
    })
    console.log("Aucun email detecté.")
    return;
  } else
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@name, 'Discord')]"
```

it will give you a list with elements. And if the list length is 0, then there is no elements found. This way you won't get any Exception

```
if (driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@name, 'Discord')]")).length !== 0) {
        fs.writeFile("NOTTHIS.txt", '${String(await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@name, 'Discord')]")))}', err => {
          if (err) throw err;
        })
        console.log("Aucun email detecté.")
        return;
      } else
```

Comment: Getting error : `driver.findElements(...).size is not a function`

Comment: Same error with length : `driver.findElements(...).length is not a function`

Comment: I have updated the code, try it. Not that familiar with node js syntaxis

Comment: Should be working, but not working in my case yet, i mark this as solved =)